# How to disable back button in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my project when we select item a item i am showing the details in next controllers but i have i am getting the details using Libxml, I have to **disable the back button** while loading the page how is it possible, please help me

Thank You

Comment: -1 because the back button should never be disabled.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc If this was true, Apple would have never made the `hidesBackButton` property.

Comment: And what if I need to disable the back button under some circumstance? In my business I need to disable the back button once user started his job and only enable if user want to cancel the job and start again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

When you're done loading,

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

when you start loading the data, and set it to no when your data is loaded.

Or you could add that code to the viewcontrollers viewWillAppear section and then again show the nav bar once the view is loaded.